# Proving that if $f'$ has at most $n-1$ zeros, then $f$ has at most $n$ zeros

Tags: analysis

Is this proof correct?

The problem is the following.

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and that the following equation has at most $n-1$ solutions:
>   $$f'(x)=0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
>   Prove that the following equation has at most $n$ solutions:
>   $$f(x)=0,\quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My proof is:

Let $f'(x)=0$ have solutions $x_1$, $x_2,\ldots ,x_{n-1}$.

since 
$$f'(x_1)=\lim\limits_{{x}\to{x_1}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1} = 0$$
and doing so, $f(x)=f(x_{n-1})$
Therefore $f(x)=f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\cdots=f(x_{n-1})$.

Let $x_n$ be one of solutions of $f(x)=0$.
$$0=f(x_n)=f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\cdots=f(x_{n-1}),$$ 
so $f(x)=0$ has solutions like $x_1$, $x_2,\ldots, x_n$.

If there is wrong part, please let me know.

Comment: +1 for showing your work (even if the work is incorrect; at least you're trying!)

Answer (score 10):

1. You cannot simply assume that $f'(x)$ is a polynomial. That is not given in the problem, and there are plenty of other functions that can have a specific number of zeros.  (Also, the problem says that $f'(x)=0$ has **at most** $n-1$ solutions, not that it has **exactly** $n-1$ solutions, yet you assume it has this maximum).
2. Even if you know that $f'(x)$ is a polynomial, you do not know that the degree is at most $n-1$; it's possible for a polynomial to have degree strictly larger than $k$, and yet have only $k$ distinct real roots.
3. It's false that the fact that $f'(x_1)=0$ implies that $f(x_1)=0$.
4. The statement "and doing so, $f(x)=f(x_{n-1})$" makes no sense to me.
5. You never showed that there are at most $n$ solutions to $f(x)=0$.
6. You seem to believe that the same numbers that are zeros of the derivative are zeros of the original function. This is not true, even for polynomials. $f(x) = x^2 - 3x + 2$ has zeros at $x=1$ and $x=2$, but the zero of $f'(x) = 2x-3$ is at $x=\frac{3}{2}$.

So, I would say that pretty much all of this argument is incorrect.

**Suggestion.** Either use the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem), or use [Darboux's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29)

Here's how an argument using the latter would go:

Suppose the zeros of the derivative are $a_1\lt a_2 \lt\cdots \lt a_{n-1}$. By Darboux's Theorem, the derivative cannot change signs except at the points where it is equal to $0$. That means, for example, that it is either always positive or it is always negative on $(-\infty,a_1)$. That means that $f(x)$ is strictly monotone on $(-\infty,a_1)$: either strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing. How many zeros can a strictly monotone function have? So, how many zeros can $f(x)$ have on $(-\infty,a_1)$?

What about $(a_1,a_2)$? $(a_2,a_3)$? Etc.

But I suspect you'll want to use the Mean Value Theorem; Darboux's Theorem is not often covered in basic analysis courses.

Comment: I want to prove it by Mean value theorem. But, I don't know how to apply it. Please help me. ;_;

Comment: @Jihyun Kim: Other people have given you plenty of hints/help in that respect, which is why I did not feel the need to do so myself. If $f(a)=f(b)=0$, what does the Mean Value Theorem tell you about the derivative on $[a,b]$?

Comment: f'(x)=0 for x in (a,b).

Comment: @Jihyun: To precise: *there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$.*. So, if between any two zeros of $f(x)$ there is at least one zero of $f'(x)$, and there are at most $n-1$ zeros of $f'(x)$, then there are at most how many "in between"s for the zeros of $f$? And with that many "in between"s, how many zeros of $f$ can you have?

Comment: There are n in betweens.

Comment: I proved it again.

Suppose that f(x)=0 has more that n solutions.
Let x1<x2<...<xn+1 be solutions of f(x)=0.
By M.V.T, there are a1,a2,..,an with x1<a1<x2<a2<...<an<xn+1 such that f'(ai)=0 for all i.
So f'(x) has at most n solutions. This is contradiction. 
Therefore f(x) has at most n solutions. 

Is this right?

Comment: @Jihyun: (i) You didn't prove it the first time, so you cannot be proving it "again." (ii) There's no need to argue by contradiction. (iii) Your conclusion before the contradiction is that $f'(x)$ has **at least** (not "at most") $n$ solutions. But essentially correct now.

Answer (score 5):

Use the mean value theorem.

Fix $n=3$. (The argument generalizes for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Suppose $f(x)=0$ has more than three (distinct) solutions, say $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$. Then the mean value theorem (Rolle's Theorem) implies that there exist $c, d, e \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1 < c < x_2 < d < x_3 < e < x_4$ and $f'(c)=f'(d)=f'(e)=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that clear on what you're doing, but your solution looks wrong. Just the conclusion that $f$ is zero at the the zeros of $f'$ (you have $n$ of them, by the way) is clearly false in general. You seem to be trying to do some variable point argument with $x$, and using the fact that the limit is zero to conclude that individual terms are zero.

A valid solution is to note that there is a zero of $f'$ between any two zeros of $f$ by the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)=0$ has more than n solutions and then show that then $f'(x)=0$ would have more than $n-1$ solutions.

It's a proof by contrapositive.

Instead of showing that $a\implies b$, you show that $\neg b \implies \neg a$.