# Show that $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie^{b_ix}$ is identically zero or has at most $n$ zeroes.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, roots

I'm working on the following question from a past Masters' exam in Analysis:

> Prove the following: 
> (a) If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere and $f'$ has at most $n$ distinct zeros, then $f$ has at most $n+1$ distinct zeros. 
> (b) If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{b_i x}$ (where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real numbers), then either $f$ is identically zero or it has at most $n$ distinct zeros.

Part (a) has already been answered here: [Proving that if $f'$ has at most $n-1$ zeros, then $f$ has at most $n$ zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39998/proving-that-if-f-has-at-most-n-1-zeros-then-f-has-at-most-n-zeros). I'm trying to use induction to prove part (b) using part (a). Here's what I tried so far:

In the base case $n=1$ we have that $f(x)=a_0+a_1e^{b_1x}$ for $a_0,a_1,b_1\in\mathbb R$. Suppose $f$ is not identically zero. The only case where $f$ is nonconstant is when $a_1\neq 0$ and $b_1\neq 0$, and in this case it's easy to show $f$ is injective so that it has at most one zero.

So suppose the statement holds for $k$. I want to show it holds for $k+1$, so I let $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_ie^{b_ix}$. Then we have that $f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_ib_ie^{b_ix}$. I get stuck trying to show that $f'$ has at most $k$ zeros. I know by our assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^k a_ib_ie^{b_ix}$ has at most $k$ zeros, but I'm not sure how that helps. Any hints here?

Comment: Hint: if you divide your formula for $f'(x)$ through by the nowhere zero function $e^{b_1x}$, you get an instance of the inductive hypothesis (which you should take to say that what you are trying to prove is true for any $a_i$ and $b_i$).

Comment: @RobArthan OMG I cannot believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @RobArthan So dividing through by say, $e^{b_{k+1}x}$ gives us $a_{k+1}b_{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^k a_ib_ie^{(b_i-b_{k+1})x}$, which has at most $k$ zeros by hypothesis, so then $f'$ must also have at most $k$ zeros because $e^{b_{k+1}x}$ is nonzero.

Comment: It's not very easy to read the superscripts in the comments on my laptop. You should divide through by $\exp(b_1 \cdot x)$ (for example: any $b_i$ would do).

Comment: @RobArthan yes, I divided by $\exp(b_{k+1}x)$

Comment: What you have done is fine: you can divide by $exp(b_{i} \cdot x)$ for any $i$. I chose $i = 1$ because I think it makes the algebra and notation easier, but $i = k +1$ is fine too.